# Unix/Linux - Advantage of relative path names over absolute path names

Tags: filenames

I am trying to figure out what are the benefits of using relative path names over absolute path names. I know what each one is.

I guess that it is easy to work with relative path names when we have long path to the current location. 
For example - The command mkdir:

mkdir backup/old ---->  : relative path ---->Better

mkdir /home/me/backup/old  ----> : absolute path

But I am trying to find another advantage (just one) for relative path names and I can`t find.

Would you please explain more about this issue?

Comment: Relative paths usually accommodate staging of distro packages. Also see [`DESTDIR`](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/DESTDIR.html) in the GNU Coding Standards.

Answer (score 1):

1. Quicker and easier to type, so less chance of a mistake
2. Portable (location independent) when creating symbolic links

Comment: Can you explain the second advantage, please?

Answer (score 1):

> Advantage of relative path names over absolute path names

A big advantage of relative paths is accommodate staging of distro packages when using a standard filesystem layout. For example, if a binary in `/usr/bin/` needs data in `/usr/share/`, then a `DATADIR` of `../share/` means the binary can be installed anywhere and the binary can locate its data.

The situation often arises in staged installs using `DESTDIR`. Instead of installing into `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` using `BINDIR` alone, the package can be located in `/opt/usr/` which equates to `$(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)` with `DESTDIR=/opt/` and `PREFIX=/usr`. The binary is located at `BINDIR=/opt/usr/bin` and the data is located at `DATADIR=/opt/usr/bin/../share`.

Also see [`DESTDIR`](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/DESTDIR.html) in the GNU Coding Standards.

Comment: Do you please have a simple example? I am not an expert at Linux.......

Answer (score 0):

Take `configure` script of any open source software.

E.g. if you have git repo `new_editor` with 2 submodules and you're writing an installation script for it, you can't write:

```
#!/bin/bash
#.........
/home/kashyap/workspaces/new_editor/module1/install.sh
/home/kashyap/workspaces/new_editor/module2/install.sh
#.........
```

You should write

```
#!/bin/bash
#.........
./module1/install.sh
./module2/install.sh
#.........
```

Comment: I can`t see the difference from my example --> its still making life easier. That is already understood. I need something else, please!